# How to use a cli variable in AWSCLI query

Tags: bash, aws-cli

***How do I use a variable with an AWS query??***

There does not seem to documentation on the query syntax, mearly examples.

Im trying to do the following:

```
API_ID=$(aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query 'items[?name == `${API_NAME}`] | [0].{id: id}' --output text)
```

The problem is that ${API_NAME} is read literally. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21):

I figured this out after sometime...

AWS uses [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/specification.html), as the spec for their `--query` option. 
When passing jmespath filter expression as a string:

> You can use double quotes (") instead and wrap the variable in single quotes ('). This will not prevent the variable from being replaced.

***So it worked when I changed it to:***

```
API_ID=$(aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query "items[?name == '${API_NAME}'] | [0].{id: id}" --output text)
```